# ERROR: Setting up your full-stack XM Cloud local development environment

Tags: xm-cloud

I'm getting the following error when trying to get my local XM up and running per this article:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--setting-up-your-full-stack-xm-cloud-local-development-environment.html

**Error**:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Unable to connect to the remote server
At C:\DEV\XM-Cloud-Introduction\up.ps1:95 char:23
+ ...   $status = Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:8079/api/http/routers ...
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this problem?
**NOTE**: I had everything working just fine the last time I ran `./up.ps1` about a month ago.

Comment: Have you tried running down.ps1 and then up.ps1 again? It seems to be an issue with traefik. I would see my docker to check if traefik is coming up without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the resolution provided my others you may also try listing the network used-

```
docker network ls
```

And prune-

```
docker network prune
```

Fo me this resolved the issue and was able to porceed.

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not remove unused resources automatically. Unnecessary resources can therefore accumulate over time and use up disk space.

**Resolution 1:** I did encounter this with container setup and It was due to a lack of free disk space. Clear disk space, use the `docker system prune -a` to remove unused Docker images.

This command removes:

1. All stopped containers.
2. All networks are not used by at least one container.
3. All dangling images (not tagged and not referenced by any container).
4. All build caches.

`-a (or --all)` - Removes all images without at least one container associated with them.

Reference: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/sitecore-docker-cheat-sheet.html

**Resolution 2:** Although my machine had `.NET Core SDK versions 3.1` and `.NET SDK 5.0` (installed as part of VS 2019) the above error occurred, `.Net SDK 6.0` is needed to resolve the error. In other words, after the install you must be able to see the `6.0.xxx` folder as in scr shot below:

[image]

Reference: https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2022/01/another-cause-for-generic-sitecore.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running `down.ps1` and `up.ps1` a couple of cycles and everything magically started working.  I haven't had time to figure out the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the same issue by following below steps:

1. run `./down.ps1`
2. run `docker system prune -a`
3. **Stopped the IIS**, whenever we are running docker we need to make sure IIS is stopped. I think this was the main reason for me to face the above issue in the first place.
4. run `./init.ps1`
5. run `./up.ps1`